# Using kbhit() for standard library

Tags: c

Is there a function or a script that performs the same job as kbhit() but using only standard C libraries? I have a project where I need to create a Pong game using only standard C libraries. kbhit() is a function I find necessary to use, but I can't. I appreciate your help or any advice

Comment: No, such things are not possible using plain standard C. You need to use OS-specific functions.

Comment: You will also have trouble implementing your animations (can be achieved via terminal control codes, probably, but with a lot of pain and assuming very specific environment)

Comment: ... or on *any* site before.

Comment: @EugeneSh. curses will come to the rescue

Comment: Do you count a common library like "ncurses" a standard C library, or are you limited to the libraries the ISO standard describes?

Comment: @gulpr Sure, but it is hardly a standard library

Answer (score 1):

As others already mentioned in the comments, there is no C Standard Library API that allows you to do that.

But it is also not true that you need to rely on OS specific or 3rd party libraries. It is possible using a POSIX compliant standard library implementation. Here is a minimal working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int my_kbhit() {
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(0, &fds);
    select(1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    return FD_ISSET(0, &fds);
}

int main(void) {

  // for this to work, we have to disable
  // the behavior of the terminal to only
  // send data after a full line has been
  // submitted
  struct termios ttystate;
  tcgetattr(0, &ttystate);
  ttystate.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
  ttystate.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &ttystate);

  // test loop
  char k = '\0';
  int c = 0;
  do {
      sleep(1);
      printf("[%9d] Press 'x' to exit this loop...\n", c++);
      if (my_kbhit() !=0) {
          k = fgetc(stdin);
          printf("Key pressed: %c\n", k);
      }
  } while (k != 'x');    

  // restore the "usual" behavior
  ttystate.c_lflag |= ICANON;
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &ttystate);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: POSIX is the specification for Unix-like operating systems. It's very much OS-specific, as is the code you show.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude being valid for an armada of different operating systems is quite the contrary from _specific_. Of course, when you extend your scope and consider a wide bunch of non-POSIX-compliant operating systems as well, you have to dive into the details of that particular OS. However, the statement, that you "need to use" OS-specific functions, is simply wrong, when you have an open standard that covers almost every relevant desktop OS, including Microsoft Windows when you count in 3rd party compatibility layers like e.g. Cygwin.